# Задачи с Яндекс.Практикума Пробный курс по алгоритмам

Tags: python, python-3.x

Решил порешать задачки с Яндекс.Практикума по алгоритмам. Добрался до алгоритма со спиральным выводом массива. 
**Суть задачи:**
*Первая строка содержит целое нечётное число m в диапазоне от 1 до 1000 — количество строк и столбцов матрицы.
В каждой из следующих m строк даны m целых чисел в диапазоне от -1000 до 1000, разделённых пробелом.
Формат вывода
Нужно вывести значения в матрице, начиная с центра по спирали. Движение вверх, далее по часовой стрелке. Каждое число выводится в отдельной строке.* 
Денёк обмозговав написал такой код:

```
def spiral(m, matrix):
    result = ''
    x = m // 2
    y = m // 2
    s = m - 1
    for i in range(0, m ** 2):
        result += f'{matrix[y][x]}\n'
        sum = x + y
        if x <= y:
            if sum <= s:
                y -= 1
            else:
                x -= 1
        elif x > y:
            if sum < s:
                x += 1
            else:
                y += 1
    return result

f = open('input.txt', 'r')
file = f.readlines()
f.close()
m=int(file.pop(0))
mass = [[int(n) for n in string.rstrip().split(' ')] for string in file]
del file
o = open('output.txt','w')
o.write(spiral(m,mass))
o.close()
```

Код выполняет требуемые действия, однако проверку по памяти не проходит. Так как зелёный, не очень представляю, как Python работает с памятью. Пробовал удалять списки после работы с ними, вынес запись матрицы в генератор, вынес проход по спирали в функцию, сократил условия. Может кто-то что посоветует?

Comment: сразу выводите а не формируйте строку.

Comment: Пробовал, бесполезно. нужно в 38МБ уложиться. При m=991 растет до 42.

Comment: `int` замените на что-то более компактное (`short` есть в питоне?)

Comment: нет, тип данных, я так подозреваю, тут не причём, дело в алгоритме. Числа в Python есть int и float. Int должен занимать меньше места чем str

Comment: для начала попробуйте не читать весь файл целиком. У вас одновременно в какой-то момент и файл в памяти и список (это может метров 5 выиграть).